# How can I combine two VBA code sequences?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I am pulling data from and creating separate spreadsheets for each line.  This code works perfectly.  There are approximately 400 lines to be moved to separate worksheets.  After each worksheet, I would like to then 'move' the worksheet to a separate workbook and delete the sheet.  The code that I have to copy the data to a workbook works perfectly also.

However, I want to change the coding into one step and just create a new workbook using the naming convention that I have in my current code to end up with approximately 400 workbooks. How can I combine these codes?

I have tried searching for answers and have tried to also combine the code but I am still quite new to VBA and mostly just 'play' with it.  I have researched here and on other sites, but have had no luck.

Here is my code:

```
Sub NewSheetPerName()
    Dim wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet, curWS As Worksheet, x As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = wb.Worksheets("Consolidated")

    For x = 8 To Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set curWS = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        curWS.Name = Ws.Cells(x, 1).Value & " " & Ws.Cells(x, 2).Value
        Sheets.FillAcrossSheets Ws.Range("1:7")
        Ws.Rows(x).Copy curWS.Range("A8")
    Next x

End Sub


Sub MoveSheetsToWorkbooks()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, strFilepath As String

    strFilepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      Ws.Copy
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFilepath & ActiveSheet.Name
      ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "All Done", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure you have a good reason but just because I'm curious what's the need for a separate sheet for each row?

Comment: Only because I'm new to VBA and am not sure how to just create a new workbook for each row. This is something that I'm trying for a coworker and they need a separate workbook for each.  If I knew how to go straight to a new workbook and still copy the data and name the file as I have designated, that would be best.  I have just been trying to find code help and couldn't find the combined code.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ya it does. I can put something together but someone will probably beat me to it because it's been years since I've messed with VBA. In Python I could do it in literally 30 seconds lol. Hold on a bit.

Comment: That will be awesome!   Thank you!

Comment: when saving the workbook what filename do you intend to use? from your code it is always the activesheet name or do you mean just get the current sheet name in the loop? your filename shoud have an extension name like `.xlsx`

Comment: It will be the current sheet name in the loop and should be an xlsm file?  The spreadsheet has school names and school number so needs to keep that naming.  Can they be a macro enabled file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generate Workbooks Per Name

```vb
Sub GenerateWorkbooksPerName()
    
    Const REPEATING_ROWS As Long = 7
    Const NAME_DELIMITER As String = " "
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Consolidated")
    
    Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = REPEATING_ROWS + 1
    
    With sws.UsedRange ' assuming row 1 is not empty:
        If .Rows.Count < FirstRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Copy ' copy the worksheet to a new single-worksheet workbook
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
    
    With dws.UsedRange ' assuming row 1 is not empty:
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - REPEATING_ROWS).Offset(REPEATING_ROWS).Clear
    End With
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Cells(FirstRow, "A")
    
    Dim dFolderPath As String:
    dFolderPath = swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    Dim ndLen As Long: ndLen = Len(NAME_DELIMITER)
    
    Dim r As Long, dCount As Long, dFilePath As String, dName As String
    
    For r = FirstRow To sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        sws.Rows(r).Copy dfCell
        dName = CStr(sws.Cells(r, "A").Value) & NAME_DELIMITER _
            & CStr(sws.Cells(r, "B").Value)
        ' or:
        'dName = CStr(dws.Cells(FirstRow, "A").Value) & NAME_DELIMITER _
            & CStr(dws.Cells(FirstRow, "B").Value)
        If Len(dName) > ndLen Then
            dws.Name = dName
            dFilePath = dFolderPath & dName & ".xlsm"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
                dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            dCount = dCount + 1
        End If
    Next r
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox dCount & " workbook" & IIf(dCount = 1, "", "s") & " generated.", _
        IIf(dCount = 0, vbCritical, vbInformation)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to toy around with this a little but it should get you started. If you need more help let me know. Also make sure you have a copy of the original file just in case.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wbPaste As Workbook
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim NewWbName As String
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wbCopy = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets("Consolidated")
    
    lrow = wsCopy.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row

    For i = 2 To lrow 'loop from 2nd row in worksheet to last row that contains data
        Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\template.xlsx") 'path to template workbook
        Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        With wsPaste
            wsCopy.Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Copy .Range("A1:C1") 'copy current row for columns A:C
            NewWbName = wsCopy.Cells(i, "A") 'name the new workbook according to the value in current row, column A
        End With
        
        wbPaste.SaveAs wbPaste.Path & Application.PathSeparator & NewWbName & ".xlsx"
        wbPaste.Close False 'close template
        
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```